# Adbe Air run time detection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have created an adobe air application. When I copy the release build (.air application) to a pc that is not installed AIR, it shows the application with "Open With" command. Is there anyway that I can show users to install air run time if they haven't installed it before installing myapplication?

Answer (score 1):

If you distribute your app via websie, you can add a badge there, if a user don't have AIR on his computer, he will be promted to install it. Take a closer look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_badge_install.html)

Comment: according to this i need to have a website to download the application right?

Comment: @Shanaka "to PROVIDE download" (to offer user to download and install app right from the browser with AIR detection thing). Another option might be AIR Captive Runtime http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader